# Set a float in cellForRow.. and return it in heightForRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a custom cell with a label in it. What I want to do is make the label `sizeToFit` in `cellForRow...` and pass the labels height to a variable called `labelHeight`. Then in `heightForRow...` I want to return `labelHeight`.

The problem is, that it returns a height of 0. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [customCell.label sizeToFit];
    self.labelHeight = customCell.label.frame.size.height;
    ...
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    return self.labelHeight;
}
```

Comment: That will never work. `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called for many rows long before `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is ever called.

Comment: So what can I do to fix that?

Comment: You have to determine the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` without first creating a cell for the row.

Comment: So how do I make `sizeThatFits` in `heigtForRow`? (It's a custom cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a very good solution for this as `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You could:

- Calculate the height of the cell on `heightForRowAtIndexPath` by calculating the size that the amount of text with the specific font (style and size) will take:

  ```
  CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];    
  CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
  ```

or you can simulate the whole view in order to have a more precise (but will be computationally much more expensive) or

- Reload the tableview after you have calculated the cell height on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I can do the first solution, but the only problem is, that its a custom cell, and I don't know how to access the cells properties from `heightForRow`

Comment: added more explanation about how to compute the size of the string in the cell.

Comment: I made an `nsLog`  of  `adjustedHeigh`, and it kept on looping a certain number. I then returned `adjustedHeight`, and the selected cell, and all cells under, got removed.

Comment: you should use the `sizeWithAttributes` to calculate the maximum height of your cells. How are you doing that at the moment?

Comment: i don't understand. I have a set height for the cell, then I want to add the labels height

Comment: My bad. I had `[tableView reloadData]` in `cellForRow`, so that's why it was looping. This is the correct answer. Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing to calculate the heightForRowAtIndexPath the simplest (although it feels inefficient way) is to call cellForRowAtIndexPath from with heightForRow... then get call reload on the table which will again call cellForRow... This feels quite dirty because of the double creation of the cell and if you are able to simplify the height calculation factoring in the known constants with the dynamic ones this might be more efficient but more code. eg.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  NSString *string = self.objects[indexPath.row];
  NSDictionary *textAttributes = nil; //attributes here

  return self.someButton.frame.size.height +
        self.someSwitch.frame.size.height +
        [string boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                    attributes:textAttributes
                       context:nil].size.height;
}
```

A better solution, if you are able to support iOS 8+ and are using autolayout, is to set the `-estimatedRowHeight` property on the tableView to a non zero value then the UILayoutConstraints on the cell will be able to calculate this for you. This is a new a very welcome addition to tableViews in iOS8 and was described in one of the WWDC videos. But it doesn't work without autolayout on the cells.